# how to pull number of comments into a php variable with facebook comments?

Tags: php, facebook-comments

I'm using fb comments on my website, and I need to pull the number of comments into a php variable so I can manipulate it. how do I do so? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `commentsbox_count` from the [`link_stat`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) FQL table, [example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=select%20commentsbox_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%20%27http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/31/dramacrunch/%27):

```
select commentsbox_count from link_stat where url = 'http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/31/dramacrunch/'
```

PHP example:

```
$query = urlencode("select commentsbox_count from link_stat where url = 'http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/31/dramacrunch/'");
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=$query"), TRUE);
if(!empty($response['data'][0]['commentsbox_count'])) {
    echo $response['data'][0]['commentsbox_count'] . " comments were found!";
}
```